# What does the | (pipe) operator do?

Tags: symbols, ilog

My colleague forwarded me some code as below. I want to understand how symbol `|` operates. I have a rough idea that it is looping through `NutritionData` Tuple and storing **unique** values of `food` into string `Foods`. But is there something that I am missing? I searched for `|` online but wasnt able to find anything.

```
tuple FoodNutrition
{
    key string food;
    key string nutrient;
    float amountPerServing;
};


{FoodNutrition} NutritionData = ...;

{string} Foods = {nd.food | nd in NutritionData};
{string} Nutrients = {nd.nutrient | nd in NutritionData};
```

Comment: Resource recommendations are off-topic for SO. Since the rest of your question seems legitimate I just nuked the intro paragraph.

Comment: Also, if you have a rough idea, why not verify it by running this code?

Comment: Last but not least you might want to ask your colleague for a link to the reference for the language above, I can't really find it in the ILOG docs either.

Comment: any idea where can i put "resource recommendation" questions?

Comment: i ran the code and thats how i realize that it stores only UNIQUE values. but would like to hear from experts on this site...also not sure what "{string} Foods" defines...does it define a string array?

Comment: Going by the sad state of the tag page for [tag:ilog], I'd say it's more likely you'll find a suitable expert at your office. Going by the notation, I'm **wildly guessing** that `{string}` is a set of strings, and the syntax you're asking about and what it does is very similar to [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) from mathemathics. (The unique values would be implied by the fact it's a set.)